# Is the corrected HTML code fully correct?

Tags: html, css

```
<table width=”250 style=”border-size: 1px solid red”>
    <tr>
     <a href=”www.google.com”  target=”blank”><h1>Google</h1></a>
</tr>
</table>
```

Corrected to

```
<table style="width:250 ; border: 1px solid red">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <a href="https://www.google.com"  target="_blank"> <h1>Google</h1> 
         </a>
      </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1) I replaced the ” with "
As my text editor did not recognize the curly colon

2) Added

3) Added "https://" to the link
...

Did I miss any correction?

Did I make any unnecessary correction?

Comment: I suggest you to go on https://validator.w3.org/check to check it. Btw you can't put 250 without a unit in inline CSS.

Comment: I wouldn't use <h1> inside <a> and use a css file for your styling

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that in the first section of code you have

```
<table width="250" style="border-size: 1px solid red;">
    <tr>
     <a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank"><h1>Google</h1></a>
    </tr>
</table>
```

the quotation marks around *www.google.com* are not normal quotation marks. I changed them when I was testing your code and it works fine. Replace them with normal ascii quotation marks and you should be fine: ""

Comment: True indeed, but the code will still run even if that table is messed up. The bigger issue is the odd quotation marks that would break his code even if he looked and saw all of the unbalanced quotes and semicolons